# get value from single node xml

Tags: xml, xpath, selectsinglenode

i have the data xml like this:

```
 <ListeNoeuds>
    <Noeud>
       <Cle>Commande</Cle>
         <Attributs>
        <Noeud>
          <Cle>nbrActionTraitees</Cle>
          <Valeur>25</Valeur>
        </Noeud> 
       <Noeud>
            <Cle>nbrErreurs</Cle>
            <Valeur>32</Valeur>
        </Noeud>
         <Noeud>
             <Cle>SujetEmail</Cle>
             <Valeur>Compte rendu du défichage Préventel XXXXXXXX</Valeur>                   </Noeud>
       </Attributs>
         <SousNoeuds>
            <Noeud>
```

.....

i just want to extract the value, where the cle = SujetEmail.
that meant i want to get this value : Compte rendu du défichage Préventel XXXXXXXX

i have tried :

```
string Sujetmail = paramsXml.SelectSingleNode("/ListeNoeuds/Noeud/Attributs/Noeud/Cle[text()='SujetEmail']).InnerText;
```

to get the value of the cle. it is work.

but when i modify to get the value of the valeur like this:

```
string Sujetmail = paramsXml.SelectSingleNode("/ListeNoeuds/Noeud/Attributs/Noeud/Cle[text()='SujetEmail']/following-sibling").InnerText;
```

i got null

i have tried also like this:

```
string Sujetmail = paramsXml.SelectSingleNode("/ListeNoeuds/Noeud/Attributs/Noeud/Cle[text()='SujetEmail']/following-sibling::string[1]").ToString();
```

got null..help me please.

Answer (score 1):

The correct XPath is

```
/ListeNoeuds/Noeud/Attributs/Noeud[Cle/text()='SujetEmail']/Valeur
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
paramsXml.SelectSingleNode("/ListeNoeuds/Noeud/Attributs/Noeud[Cle[text()='SujetEmail']]/Valeur").InnerText;
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks you for responding...i found my solution like this:

```
 XmlNode FindSujet = paramsXml.SelectSingleNode("/ListeNoeuds/Noeud/Attributs/Noeud/Cle[text()='SujetEmail']");
            string Sujetmail =  FindSujet.NextSibling.InnerText;
```